# Which Scripture mentions the famous Shiva Tandava Stotram?

Tags: scripture, shiva, ravana, stotra

Shiva Tandava Stotram is a hymn dedicated to Lord Shiva and it describes the daily evening dance of Tandava. It also poetically describes destroying aspects of Shiva. Shiva Tandava Stotram mentioned by Dr. Sarasvati Mohan on [Sanskrit documents website](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivTAND_meaning.html) has two Slokas which are less known.

> निलिम्प नाथनागरी कदम्ब मौलमल्लिका- 
>  निगुम्फनिर्भक्षरन्म
>   धूष्णिकामनोहरः । 
>  तनोतु नो मनोमुदं विनोदिनींमहनिशं 
>  परिश्रय
>   परं पदं तदङ्गजत्विषां चयः ॥ १४॥
>
> प्रचण्ड वाडवानल प्रभाशुभप्रचारणी 
>  महाष्टसिद्धिकामिनी जनावहूत
>   जल्पना । 
>  विमुक्त वाम लोचनो विवाहकालिकध्वनिः 
>  शिवेति
>   मन्त्रभूषगो जगज्जयाय जायताम् ॥ १५॥

The above two slokas are not known to many. I checked for Shiva Tandava Stotram in two variants of Uttara Kanda of Ramayana ([Manmatha Nath Ramayana](https://archive.org/details/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam) and [on this site](http://ramayana.tigercoder.com/)). Both of them don't have Shiva Tandava Stotram.

What Scripture (Ithihasa or Purana or any Smriti) has Shiva Tandava Stotram? Please provide Sankrit text if possible.

Comment: I think the whole Shiva Tandava stotra came as independent text without being embedded in any Itihasa and Purana... like Ashtavakra Gita..

Comment: @Tezz As discussed before, [Ravananugraha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravananugraha) could also be source where Ravana got mightiest Atmalingam of Shiva.

Comment: Ravana sung the Shiva tandava stortam. This can be found from Shiva stotra paadlagal [collection of small songs on Lord shiva.

Comment: Found something, will be posting as an answer.

Comment: The above mentioned verses are not in the source website also. Where did you find them?

Comment: @SreeCharan i think  they updated now. Wiki copied Sanskritdocuments and those verses are available on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Tandava_Stotram).

Comment: Pancaamar Chanda (पञ्चचामर छन्द) is not a text, it's the meter in which the stotram is sung.

Answer (score 7):

[Shiv Tandava Strotam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Tandava_Stotram)([शिवताण्डवस्तोत्रम्](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5_%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%B5_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0)) is a [hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stotra) or eulogy([ode of praise](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/the-shiva-tandava-stotra)) dedicated to Lord Shiva, it poetically describes [the beauty](http://www.theshivaexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ardhanareeswara-form-of-hindu-god-shiva-goddess-parvati-300x277.jpg) and power of Lord Shiv in every aspect possible.

It is [said](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-slokas-or-stotras-in-Sanskrit/answer/Minakhi-Prasad-Misra?srid=t5m7) that the strotam was [created and sung](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2684/314) by [Raavana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana). He was so filled with ego that [he tried to lift Mount Kailash](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/devon-ke-dev-mahadev/12/dashanan-is-named-ravana/1000000634), but then almighty Shiva [when he was](https://youtu.be/sawvbnAIoIM?t=6m58s) out his toe on the Earth, thus Ravana's hands got stuck! He started crying, and began singing to [please lord Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravananugraha).

The original scripture is not known!

Its chhanda is Panchaamar Chhand(पञ्चचामर छन्द).

> पञ्च-चामर छन्द में लघु -दीर्घ [१२ x ८ =24] होते हैं, सोलह १६ वर्ण यति ८, ८ होता है
> meaning:
> `The stotra is in the Panchachaamara Chhanda. It has 16 syllables per line of the quatrain, with Laghu (short syllable) and Guru (long syllable) characters alternating`.

चार चरण का वर्णिक छंद
प्रत्येक चरण में लघु गुरु के क्रम से सोलह वर्ण / अक्षर
ल ला - ल ला - ल ला - ल ला - ल ला - ल ला - ल ला - ल ला

`रावण रचित शिव ताण्डव स्तोत्र`

> `जटाटवीगलज्जल प्रवाहपावितस्थले`
> `गलेऽवलम्ब्य लम्बितां भुजंगतुंगमालिकाम्‌।` 
> `डमड्डमड्डमड्डमनिनादवड्डमर्वयं` 
> `चकार चंडतांडवं तनोतु नः शिवः शिवम।`

Some say that Raavan [took inspiration](http://www.saivism.net/prayers/tandava.asp) from [Sam veda](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/samveda/samveda.htm), but again strotam is not there in it, also not in [Ramayan](https://archive.org/details/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam), maybe because these events took place before the birth of Rama. Also, it might be independently available as said in above comments.

---

have sent an email to the [translation source](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivTAND_meaning.html) you mentioned, also asked my brother to provide any scriptures available.

Update: Just received a mail:

> The source is not known so most likely independent.
>
> Nandu
>
> -- Sent from my Android phone with mail.com Mail. Please excuse typos and my brevity.
>
> http://sanskritdocuments.org