# What is the source and origin of Shiv Panchaakshar Strotam?

Tags: shiva

Inspired by [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14147/314), I want to find out the source and origin of [Shiv Panchakshara Stotra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchakshara_Stotra).
Please provide with original scriptural text, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiva Panchakshar stotram was composed by Adi Shankara. There is also another Shiva Panchakshara stotra avaliable in Shiva Purana. However the popular one starting from "Nagendrahaaraya Trilochanaya.... " was composed by Adi Shankaracharya.

At the end of the stotra:

> इति श्रीमच्छङ्कराचार्यविरचितं शिवपञ्चाक्षर स्तोत्रम् सम्पूर्णं ।। 
>   Thus ends the Shiva Panchakshar Stotra composed by Adi Shankaracharya.

The full text of Shiva Panchakshara Stotra goes as:

> नागेन्द्रहाराय त्रिलोचनाय 
>   भस्माङ्गरागाय महेश्वराय । 
>   नित्याय शुद्धाय दिगम्बराय 
>   तस्मै नकाराय नमः शिवाय ॥१॥
>
> मन्दाकिनीसलिलचन्दनचर्चिताय 
>   नन्दीश्वरप्रमथनाथमहेश्वराय । 
>   मन्दारपुष्पबहुपुष्पसुपूजिताय 
>   तस्मै मकाराय नमः शिवाय ॥२॥
>
> शिवाय गौरीवदनाब्जवृन्दसूर्याय 
>   दक्षाध्वरनाशकाय । 
>   श्रीनीलकण्ठाय वृषध्वजाय 
>   तस्मै शिकाराय नमः शिवाय ॥३॥
>
> वशिष्ठकुम्भोद्भवगौतमार्यमूनीन्द्रदेवार्चितशेखराय । 
>   चन्द्रार्कवैश्वानरलोचनाय 
>   तस्मै वकाराय नमः शिवाय ॥४॥
>
> यक्षस्वरुपाय जटाधराय 
>   पिनाकहस्ताय सनातनाय । 
>   दिव्याय देवाय दिगम्बराय 
>   तस्मै यकाराय नमः शिवाय ॥५॥ 
>   
>  फलश्रुती 
>  
>   पञ्चाक्षरमिदं पुण्यं यः पठेच्छिवसंनिधौ । 
>   शिवलोकमावाप्नोति शिवेन सह मोदते ॥६॥
>
> ।।इति श्रीमच्छङ्कराचार्यविरचितं शिवपञ्चाक्षर स्तोत्रम् सम्पूर्णं।।

Comment: Which Chapter of Shiva Purana has other Panchaksari Stotram?

Comment: @The Destroyer I had read it... but I forgot the chapter... now I'm confused either it is in Shiva Purana or it is in Linga Purana...

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Could you please also share than Shiv Puraana one.