# Shiva Tandava Stotram

Tags: shiva, history, stotra

I am trying to write an article on the origin and meaning of Shiva Tandava Stotram for the general audience. I know the basic background story of how Ravana wanted to impress Lord Shiva and how this beautiful chant was composed by him. But I want to learn more about the earliest recorded versions of it? Where is it originally located in our texts? Who first made it famous? What are the deeper meanings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Scripture mentions the famous Shiva Tandava Stotram?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14147/which-scripture-mentions-the-famous-shiva-tandava-stotram)