# Did Ravana compose any music?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

In T.V. serials, Ravana is always portrayed as a demon and never shown as a musician. Did Ravana compose any music?

Comment: The Shiva Tandava Stotram can be attributed to him, which when sung by him, earned him the name Ravana

Comment: Check out this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14330/11875

Comment: Legends in some parts of India say that Ravana played an instrument called the "Ravanahata".

Comment: Ravana is credited with inventing the Rudra Veena, and was supposedly a master Veena player.